# How to set the include path, #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

Tags: opencv, yolo, darknet

I am trying to do Compiling With OpenCV section in this page: [Installing Darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/)

After I did `OPENCV = 1`, I tried to do re-make, so I did `make` in the darknet directory.

The directory is below.

```
(yolo) bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/moray/darknet
(yolo) bash-3.2$ ls
LICENSE     LICENSE.gpl LICENSE.v1  backup      data        libdarknet.a    python      src
LICENSE.fuck    LICENSE.meta    Makefile    cfg     examples    libdarknet.so   results
LICENSE.gen LICENSE.mit README.md   darknet     include     obj     scripts
```

and the result of the re-makaing is here.

```
(yolo) bash-3.2$ make
g++ -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -c ./src/image_opencv.cpp -o obj/image_opencv.o
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
./src/image_opencv.cpp:6:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/image_opencv.o] Error 1
```

So I thought include path could not reference `opencv.hpp`, I looked for the file and found it.

```
(yolo) bash-3.2$ ls ~/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
/Users/moray/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp
```

Therefore I tried to change `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` to `"include "~/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"` in `./src/image_opencv.cpp`

And the result is here.

```
(yolo) bash-3.2$ make
g++ -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DOPENCV `pkg-config --cflags opencv`  -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DOPENCV -c ./src/image_opencv.cpp -o obj/image_opencv.o
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
./src/image_opencv.cpp:7:10: fatal error: 
      '~/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include "~/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/image_opencv.o] Error 1
```

I cannot understand why the error happens.
Please tell me your think.

============================================

os: macOS Catalina 10.15.1

(yolo) is a virtual environment in anaconda(3)

opencv was installed by pip command in (yolo)

all the packages by pip command in (yolo):

```
(yolo) bash-3.2$ pip list
Package               Version            
--------------------- -------------------
certifi               2019.11.28         
numpy                 1.17.4             
opencv-contrib-python 4.1.2.30           
opencv-python         4.1.1.26           
pip                   19.3.1             
setuptools            42.0.2.post20191203
wheel                 0.33.6
```

gcc:

```
(yolo) bash-3.2$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

This error explains it `pkg-config: command not found`. In order to use OpenCV in YOLO, you have to install OpenCV that works for **C or C++** program, not Python. You probably installed opencv using pip for Python. Follow these steps in one of these links to install opencv : [this](http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/) or [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/) or other tutorial.

After that, to check whether you have installed OpenCV correctly and can be used in C program, run this command :

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

If it doesn't show anything or shows wrong version, try to reinstall OpenCV **OR** it is possible that your machine doesn't locate opencv version correctly.
 
So add command to your `~/.bashrc` for example :

```
vim ~/.bashrc
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/user/installation/OpenCV-3.4.0/lib/pkgconfig
source ~/.bashrc
```

Notes : Change the path according to your opencv installation directory that contains `opencv.pc`